# Environment variables undefined on Next.js deployment to Google Cloud Run

Tags: reactjs, docker, next.js, google-cloud-run

When deploying a Next.js application to Google Cloud Run, my environment variables are showing up as `undefined` on Google Cloud Run despite working perfectly on my local machine.

The environment variables are defined in `.env.development` and `.env.production` files

Answer (score 1):

Ok so after wasting hours on this, I managed to solve it by adding a `.gcloudignore` and `.dockerignore`. Seems that Google Cloud run automatically ignores `.env` files in the absense of these files.

Comment: I'm giving a try... It looks a very good catch. The docs say about --set-env-var, to replicate for each one :( or use the yml..

Comment: I only added a .env.production file and it works. I tried to set the env vars through the Cloud Run UI to no avail. Adding the two ignore files increased my build times by ~5 minutes and for me it works without them.